# Open Street Map Server for EPSG:4326

Tags: openstreetmap, leaflet

I would like to use the EPSG:4326 CRS in my leaflet app as I have a lot of WMS layers that are only available in EPSG:4326.

So, I'm looking for a tile service in EPSG:4326. But it seems like all the X/Y/Z links I am finding are in EPSG:3857.

Comment: I couldn't find a OSM server with tiles in EPSG:4326 but with a little effort you could [render your own tiles](http://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/) in any projection you like. Probably not the answer you are expecting, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently I do not believe that OSM has a server serving out tiles in EPSG:4326

Comment: 3 years have passed? anything new?

Answer (score 2):

Check out http://www.mapproxy.org, which would allow you to reproject OSM tiles on the fly.

Comment: This is the definitive solution. "Do not believe" can't be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You must use MapProxy:

Create a "sources.yaml":

```
sources:
  openstreetmap_source:
    type: tile
    grid: GLOBAL_WEBMERCATOR
    url: http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/%(z)s/%(x)s/%(y)s.png
    transparent: false
    request_format: image/png
    concurrent_requests: 5
    http:
      client_timeout: 600
```

Create a "caches.yaml". This will do the magic:

```
caches:
  osm_cache:
    grids: [geodetic]
    meta_size: [4, 4]
    sources: [osm_cache_in]
    request_format: image/png
    link_single_color_images: true
    concurrent_tile_creators: 4
    format: image/png
  osm_cache_in:
    sources: [openstreetmap_source]
    disable_storage: true
    grids: [GLOBAL_WEBMERCATOR]
    request_format: image/png
    link_single_color_images: true
    concurrent_tile_creators: 4
    format: image/png
```

Create a "layer.yaml"

```
layers:
  - name: openstreetmap
    title: OpenStreetMap
    sources: [osm_cache]
```

... and the "mapproxy.yaml" of course:

```
base: [layers.yaml, caches.yaml, sources.yaml]

services:
  demo:
  wms:
    srs: ['EPSG:4326','EPSG:3857']
    md:
      title: MapProxy WMS Proxy

grids:
  webmercator:
    base: GLOBAL_WEBMERCATOR
  geodetic:
    base: GLOBAL_GEODETIC
  smaps_grid:
    base: GLOBAL_MERCATOR
    srs: 'EPSG:4326'

globals:
  image:
    resampling_method: bicubic # nearest/bilinear
    paletted: false
    formats:
      image/png:
        mode: RGBA
        transparent: true    
      image/jpeg:
        encoding_options:
          # jpeg quality [0-100]
          jpeg_quality: 60
```

Now you can access OSM as WMS:

```
http://<YOUR_MAPPROXY>/mapproxy/service?LAYERS=openstreetmap&FORMAT=image%2Fjpeg ...
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Leaflet supports EPSG:4326 as well. See the [documentation](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#defined-crs-l.crs.epsg4326). You should probably try something like this:

```
L.map("id", {crs: L.CRS.EPSG4326});
```

Comment: Sure that is what I am doing.  What you are missing is that leaflet does not re-project imagery tiles.  In this case OSM coming from http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png is in EPSG:3857.  What this means is that if you set EPSG:4326 in leaflet and start throwing down points the point will be in EPSG:4326 (leaflet works) but your map is in EPSG:3857.  Try it out place a point in Alaska.

Comment: Oh, I didn't get your question right then. But as scai already pointed out, you'll probably have to render your own tiles in EPSG:4326.